What is the Microsoft goto extension?
I am writing a C++ generator, that needs to use the goto statement. I am compiling my code with clang++ and get the warning [-Wmicrosoft-goto] on some of my gotos. All of my gotos only jump around inside a single function even without stack variable declarations, and I cannot see any difference from when I get the warning to when I get no warning.
I really would like to use a C++ conforming goto, but I cannot find any information about what the Microsoft extension is.
Can you please tell me what the Microsoft goto extension is, and what triggers that warning in clang++?

EDIT:
I did have a stack variable that was being jumped over, so that is the difference. I solved it by putting the part with the stack variable in {} and now the warning does not appear anymore.
In my defense, I was hoping someone just knows what the Microsoft goto extension is, or knows better how to find a documentation that states what it is.

Showing one of your goto generating the warning might help...

Why do you think your code even needs a goto? It is always possible to write C++ code without it.

Be aware that goto is usually sign of bad code. And exception form this rule are quite rare.

Documentation of this warning is pretty poor so example would be very helpful. warning: jump from this goto statement to its label is a Microsoft extension

It seems impossible to find out exactly what this means in practice. Search engines don't find anything useful, and MS's documentation is as awful as it traditionally is. Without seeing an example, it's pretty much impossible to tell how your generated code deviates from the standard.

You could try adding curly braces between the goto and the label.  goto skip; { std::string s{"hello"}; } skip: std::cout << "Skipped to here\n";


even without stack-variable declarations

Are you sure? The only conformance flag for Visual C++ that mentions goto is /Zc:gotoScope, which flags

goto statements that jump over the initialization of one or more local variables.


This warning is in llvm clang.

@MarekR yes, it's warning about a use of goto that is nonconforming, which (used to be) accepted by Visual C++
